# Javascript Nested Function Call

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am trying to develop a javascript library that makes it easier for me to generate DOM Elements and edit their attributes. The problem I am having is that there is so many attributes for some elements that it is making for messy code. For instance I have to programmatically set the color of border, background, shadow, etc. using a method call before generation.

**See setBorder Nested in function Div in jLibrary.php**

```
function Div() {

    Div.POSITION = {

        STATIC : 'static',
        ABSOLUTE : 'absolute',
        RELATIVE : 'relative',
        FIXED : 'fixed'

    }

    Div.BORDER = {

        SOLID : 'solid',
        DOTTED : 'dotted'

    }

    Div.ALIGN = {

        LEFT : 0,
        CENTER : 1,
        RIGHT : 2,
        TOP : 0,
        MIDDLE : 1,
        BOTTOM : 2

    }

    var ELEMENT;
    var CSS;

    var horizontalAlign;
    var verticalAlign;

    var colorQueue;



    (function() {

        this.div = document.createElement('div');

        ELEMENT = this.div;
        CSS = this.div.style;


        colorQueue = 'rgb(' + new Array(0, 0, 0) + ')';


        document.body.appendChild(this.div);




    }());

    this.setPosition = function(postype) {

        if (!horizontalAlign && !verticalAlign) {

            CSS.position = postype;

        }


    }

    this.setBounds = function(x, y, width, height) {

        CSS.left = x + 'px';
        CSS.top = y + 'px';
        CSS.width = width + 'px';
        CSS.height = height + 'px';

    }

    this.setColorQueue = function(r, g, b) {

        colorQueue = 'rgb(' + new Array(r, g, b) + ')';
        alert(colorQueue);

    }

    this.setBackgroundColorToQueue = function(){

        CSS.backgroundColor = colorQueue;

    }

    this.createShadow = function(x, y, width, height){

        CSS.boxShadow = y + 'px ' + x + 'px ' + width + 'px ' + height + 'px ' + colorQueue;


    }

    this.createBorder = function(width,style){
     CSS.border = width + 'px ' + style + ' ' + colorQueue;
     /* Theoretical Method.
     this.setColor = function(r,g,b){ //This will not work the way I want it...
          CSS.border = 'rgb(' + new Array(r, g, b) + ')';
     }
     */
}

    this.rotateDiv = function(degrees){

        CSS.transform = 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)';

    }

    this.horizontalAlign = function(horiz) {

        var freeSpaceX = ((window.innerWidth - ELEMENT.offsetWidth) / 2);
        var defPadding = '8px';
        var defPaddingCenter;
        var defPaddingRight;
        var defPaddingLeft;

        horizontalAlign = true;

        if (CSS.position == 'relative' || CSS.position == 'static' || CSS.position == 'absolute') {

            CSS.position = 'absolute';
            defPaddingCenter = 4;
            defPaddingRight = 4;
            defPaddingLeft = 8;



        } else if (CSS.position == 'fixed') {

            defPaddingCenter = 4;
            defPaddingRight = 4;
            defPaddingLeft = 8;

        }

        if (horiz == 0) {

            if (!verticalAlign) {
                CSS.marginTop = defPadding;
            }
            CSS.marginLeft = defPaddingLeft + 'px';

        } else if (horiz == 1) {

            if (!verticalAlign) {
                CSS.marginTop = defPadding;
            }
            CSS.marginLeft = freeSpaceX - defPaddingCenter + 'px';

        } else if (horiz == 2) {

            if (!verticalAlign) {
                CSS.marginTop = defPadding;
            }
            CSS.marginLeft = (freeSpaceX - defPaddingRight) * 2 + 'px';

        }

    }

    this.verticalAlign = function(vertical) {

        var freeSpaceY = ((window.innerHeight - ELEMENT.offsetHeight) / 2);
        var defPadding = '8px';
        var defPaddingTop;
        var defPaddingMid;
        var defPaddingBot;

        verticalAlign = true;

        if (CSS.position == 'relative' || CSS.position == 'static') {

            CSS.position = 'absolute';

        }

        defPaddingTop = 8;
        defPaddingMid = 8;
        defPaddingBot = 8;

        if (vertical == 0) {

            if (!horizontalAlign) {
                CSS.marginLeft = defPadding;
            }
            CSS.marginTop = defPadding;


        } else if (vertical == 1) {

            if (!horizontalAlign) {
                CSS.marginLeft = defPadding;
            }
            CSS.marginTop = freeSpaceY - defPaddingMid + 'px';


        } else if (vertical == 2) {

            if (!horizontalAlign) {
                CSS.marginLeft = defPadding;
            }
            CSS.marginTop = (freeSpaceY * 2) - defPaddingBot + 'px';

        }

    }



}
```

**setBorder Example in index.php**

```
var div1 = new Div();
div1.setPosition(Div.POSITION.ABSOLUTE);
div1.setBounds(0,700, 200,200);
div1.setColorQueue(0,0,0); //This method must be called every time a different color is needed for a certain attribute.
div1.createBorder(5, Div.BORDER.SOLID); // I really want something like this --> div1.createBorder(5,Div.BORDER.SOLID).setColor(0,0,0);
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe the `this` in `this.setColor` refers to a different `this` than `this.createBorder`

Comment: you don't call `this.setColor`. Also, it would replace the border attribute instead of adding it. Did you mean to write `this.setColorQueue = function...` instead?

Comment: @Sebas Sorry. setColorQueue is what I am using right now but have to call it every time i create a border, shadow, background, etc. setColor is only a theoretical method.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ I know it refers to the Div function that I have all my methods wrapped in. I am not sure how to refer to the setColor function itself.

Comment: You might as well show us the other methods you're calling in index.php. Also, did you add these methods to the prototype of Div? How can you call them from the object?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you're asking for help with?  Are you asking how to create all the methods like `.setPosition()` and `.setBounds()` in your second example or are you asking for some more general way that doesn't require creating all those specific methods?

Comment: If you want to be able to chain methods like this `div1.createBorder(5,Div.BORDER.SOLID).setColor(0,0,0)`, then you must return `this` from each method.  It is the return value from one method that the next method in the chain operates on.

Comment: @Sebas Edited above with div function.

Comment: Question solved by Sebas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern):

```
function DivBuilder() {
    var color;
    var border;
    var position;
    var bounds;

    this.DivBuilder = function() {}

    this.color = function(c) {
        //set the color
        this.color = c;
        return this;
    }

    this.border = function(b) {
        //set the border
        this.border = b;
        return this;
    }

    this.position = function(p) {
        //set position
        this.position = p;
        return this;
    }

    this.bounds = function(b) {
        //set bounds
        this.border = b;
        return this;
    }

    this.build = function () {
        //build the new Div object with the properties of the builder
        var d = new Div(this);
        return d;
    }

}
```

and then:

```
var divb = new DivBuilder();
divb.position().bounds().border().color();
var div = divb.buid();
```

Main advantage over the [telescopic constructor pattern](https://kodelog.wordpress.com/tag/telescopic-constructor-pattern/)  (well, the adaptation of it to javascript) is that you can choose easier which property you want to initialize without having to create many different constructor cases.

Comment: What is the point of the four variable declarations at the start of your constructor?  You aren't using them anywhere.

Comment: it is because I didn't detail the code. Basically you would need a set of Builder.getProperties accessing them

Comment: @Sebas I would like to keep it nested within my createBorder method. I have been trying to return this as an object within itself but "this" being function Div is not createBorder is there a way to return the createBorder within itself?

Comment: @Sebas I was somehow able to get this to work by copying and pasting your answer in this.createBorder. and return new this.DivBuilder. Thanks for the help. Ill repost the solved version later.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write this.createBorder(...).setColor(...) It means that createBorder should return an object with the setColor method...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Sebas I was able to come up with this...

**Nested in this.createBorder()**

```
this.createBorder = function(width) {

        CSS.border = width + 'px';

        function DivBorderBuilder() {


            this.setColor = function(r, b, g) {
                alert('color');
                CSS.borderColor = 'rgb(' + new Array(r, g, b) + ')';
                return this;
            }
            
            this.setStyle = function(s){
                
                CSS.borderStyle = s;
                
                return this;
            }

        }return new DivBorderBuilder();


    }
```

**Creating Border in index.php**

```
 <script>

var div1 = new Div();
div1.setPosition(Div.POSITION.ABSOLUTE);
div1.setBounds(0,700, 200,200);
div1.createBorder(5).setStyle(Div.BORDER.SOLID).setColor(255,0,0);// Works Perfectly Now !

</script>
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe you should rename DivBuilder to DivBorderBuilder then